# How to download the p4.pm(perforce) module for Perl script?

Tags: perl, perforce, perl-module

How to download the p4.pm(perforce) module for Perl script?

Is it possible to use modules without installing them?

Answer (score 2):

> How to download

https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/projects/p4perl/archives/main.zip

> Is it possible to use modules without installing them?

Yes, see [`blib`](http://p3rl.org/blib). What's the point, though? The code *has* to sit somewhere as a file so that Perl is able to read it, then it might as well be in the intended installation directories so that [manipulating the include path](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-add-a-directory-to-my-include-path-%28%40INC%29-at-runtime%3f) becomes unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your help in this matter. let me check it.

Comment: I am getting an error while excusing script also pastes error message in below.

Comment: Can't locate auto/P4/autosplit.ix in @INC (INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib .) at C:/Perl64/lib/AutoLoader.pm line 181.
 at C:/Perl64/lib/P4.pm line 67.

Comment: Compilation failed in require at C:\Users\sysadmin\perl-excs\perforce.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Users\sysadmin\perl-excs\perforce.pl line 3.

Comment: I found the Linux version [here](http://www.perforce.com/downloads/perforce/r18.2/bin.tools/p4perl.tgz).  There isn't an obvious readme file or installation script so I have no idea what to do with it.  I vaguely recall something about a collection of C++ sources which were failing to compile when I tried this last year.  I reached out to Perforce for help at the time but they refused to speak with me because my company's license had lapsed for one week.  I'm not even sure why the code I'm working with has a runtime dependency on Perforce in the first place.  FML...

Comment: Alex Johnson, [open a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that